# Databricks Delta table / Compute job

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-live-tables

My name is Eduardo sorry for my bad English not my native language.
Im playing with Databricks with DLT and I have a question.

When a Play with regular ETL I can full manage the compute resource. I can tur on/off. But when a create a DLT Pipeline the 'job compute' is always on.

If there is an explanation about this ? Is charging me always or only when the pipeline execute.

Best regards

I create differente pipelines, and read some resources. But still don't find a direct answer

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAhr6.png)